Solana transaction expire
I am making a solana transaction from rust, and my transaction does not go through, i can only see this
[0/32] Finalizing transaction
and the number is still,
and after a while, i get this
solana - Failed to send transaction with finalized commitment: Error { request: None, kind: RpcError(ForUser("unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds")) }
i have funds, so it is not an issue of funds
i have tried all of these
set_compute_unit_limit
CommitmentConfig::confirmed()
get_latest_blockhash_with_commitment
send_and_confirm_transaction_with_spinner_and_commitment
set_compute_unit_price
but still the same behaviour
